# Prefill bootstrap modal input with value from controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to prefill my form in bootstrap modal with `ng-model` data, so I've tried something, but unsuccessfuly. Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yjyl3E?p=preview) with my code. I've tried to add resolve function with `$scope` object returning to my modalService, but it doesn't work as I expected. Could anyone help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To start with in your plunker there is no model so nothing will get displayed.

To display data inside the model you follow the same process as you would to display data else where.

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You would then fill add `{{object.name}}` following your model structure to display the data.

For example

```
<h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
```

If you're looking to use a form inside your modal then ng-model is the right thing for you and you can use it like this:

```
<form name="testForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input ng-model="name" name="anim" class="my-input"
         aria-describedby="inputDescription" />
</form>
```

This will two way bind the name property from your model to the input, which in turn will pre fill the input field. You can read more about ng-model [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Comment: Hi, I've created a service to share data betwen my maincontroller and modalcontroller, but now  I'm stuck with propagating modalOptions in my modalService. If you try this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/lHK23u?p=preview) and click on edit button, you'll see prefilled inputbox, but modalOptions disappeared. If you comment line 97 in script.js and uncomment line 98, it will show you modal I've defined by modalOptions, but now it doesn't, of course, fill my inputbox. Have you got a solution for my problem?

Comment: Your Plunkr link doesn't go anywhere.